# ¿Porque esta lista en python no se ordena correctamente de mayor a menor?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, bucle-for, ordenamiento

Estoy escribiendo el siguiente script en python y el problema lo tengo en el ultimo `for` que es el que deberia cumplir la funcion de ordenar la lista `ingreso_acomulado` de mayor a menor, paralelamente tambien ordenando la lista `lista_empleados` para que se mantengan paralelas.

La funcion del script es tomar los nombres de la cantidad de empleados que uno coloque que va a ingresar y sus ultimos 3 sueldos, luego imprimir por pantalla el total pagado a estos empleados y finalmente el nombre del que tuvo el mayor ingreso acomulado y el monto correspondiente.

La intencion de escribir el codigo de esta manera es que el script pueda funcionar sin importar la cantidad de empleados que uno ingrese.

Estoy seguro de que hay mejores maneras de hacerlo, sucede que intento armarlo con los conocimientos que tengo ahora.

```
lista_empleados = []
lista_sueldos = []
ingreso_acomulado = []


cant = int(input("Cuantos empleados ingresara?: "))


for x in range(cant):
  nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ")
  lista_empleados.append(nombre)
  
  sueldo1 = int(input("Ingrese sueldo del empleado correspondiente al 1er mes: "))
  sueldo2 = int(input("Ingrese sueldo del empleado correspondiente al 2do mes: "))
  sueldo3 = int(input("Ingrese sueldo del empleado correspondiente al 3er mes: "))
  lista_sueldos.append([sueldo1, sueldo2, sueldo3])
  
for x in range(len(lista_sueldos)):
  suma = 0
  for y in range(len(lista_sueldos[x])):
      suma = lista_sueldos[x][y] + suma
  ingreso_acomulado.append(suma)
print(ingreso_acomulado)
  
print("El total que se le pago a los empleados en los ultimos 3 meses es: ")

for x in range(len(lista_empleados)):
  print(lista_empleados[x], ingreso_acomulado[x])

print("El empleado con mayor ingreso acomulado es: ")

for x in range(len(ingreso_acomulado)-1):
  if ingreso_acomulado[x] < ingreso_acomulado[x+1]:
    aux = ingreso_acomulado[x]
    ingreso_acomulado[x] = ingreso_acomulado[x+1]
    ingreso_acomulado[x+1] = aux
    aux2= lista_empleados[x]
    lista_empleados[x] = lista_empleados[x+1]
    lista_empleados[x+1] = aux2
print(lista_empleados[0], ingreso_acomulado[0])
```

El error es que al imprimir el elemento `lista_empleados[0]`  y `ingreso_acomulado[0]` no muestra el nombre del empleado con mayor ingreso acomulado ni el monto correspondiente. Si no que muestra el elemento `[0]` de ambas listas como si nada se hubiera modificado.

Lo intente a la inversa (de menor a mayor, reemplazando el elemento `[0]` por `[-1]`) y funciono, pero quiero entender por que de esta manera no funciona ya que realmente no logro ver el error.

Como se podra apreciar, el ultimo `for` ordenaria (o tendria que hacerlo) ambas listas de tal manera que el mayor ingreso acomulado quede en el indice `[0]` de la lista `ingreso_acomulado` y el nombre del empleado que recibio ese mayor ingreso acomulado quede en el indice `[0]` de la lista `lista_empleados`.

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: A menos que se trate de un ejercicio académico en el que se te pida implementar tú mismo una ordenación, no tiene sentido que hagas una. Utiliza `sorted()` ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html)) de Python, que es muchísimo más eficiente, en combinación con su parámetro `key` para ordenaciones más complejas que la que hace por defecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El algoritmo de sort más básico es el *bubble sort*, o *sort de burbujas* [Miralo en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja)

La idea es recorrer la lista examinando cada elemento contra los que quedan por delante. Si hay un elemento que es mayor, lo intercambias y sigues buscando hasta llegar al final de la lista. Asi, cada elemento serà mayor a todos los que vienen después.

El problema con tu código es que sólo comparas cada elemento con el siguiente. Debes compararlo contra todo el resto de la lista que tiene por delante. Eso implica que necesitas dos `for` anidados.

He aqui una implementación:

```
lista_empleados=["Juan", "Pedro", "Agustin", "Maria", "Isabel", "Ana"]
ingreso_acumulado=[100, 110, 90, 120, 70, 60]

def bubble_sort(lista1, lista2):
    """ Bubble sort de dos listas paralelas.
        Ordena la primera lista de mayor a menor. Ordena la segunda
        lista para mantener la informaciòn consistente.
    """
    num = len(lista1)
    for x in range(num - 1):
        for y in range(x+1, num):
            if lista1[x] < lista1[y]:
                lista1[x], lista1[y] = lista1[y], lista1[x]
                lista2[x], lista2[y] = lista2[y], lista2[x]

def print_lista(titulo, lista1, lista2):
    print(titulo) 
    for i in range(len(lista1)):
        print("%4d %s" % (lista1[i], lista2[i]))

print_lista("Lista original", ingreso_acumulado, lista_empleados)
bubble_sort(ingreso_acumulado, lista_empleados)
print_lista("Lista ordenada", ingreso_acumulado, lista_empleados)
```

produce:

```
Lista original
 100 Juan
 110 Pedro
  90 Agustin
 120 Maria
  70 Isabel
  60 Ana
Lista ordenada
 120 Maria
 110 Pedro
 100 Juan
  90 Agustin
  70 Isabel
  60 Ana
```

**Observaciones**

El bubble sort es ineficiente. Saca de apuro en situaciones con un juego de datos minimo (unos 10-20 elementos) cuando el ambiente no ofrece una función de sort alternativa.

Comment: Gracias! Hay algo que no me quedo claro, cuando dices "El problema con tu código es que sólo comparas cada elemento con el siguiente. Debes compararlo contra todo el resto de la lista que tiene por delante." Tengo entendido que el codigo que hice compara el elemento [x] con el [x+1] que seria igual a comparar elemento [0] con elemento [1] y asi avanzando sucesivamente, eso no seria compararlos todos? Ya que si doy como parametro el largo de los elementos que contiene la lista, -1, (que seria igual a la cantidad de veces que tengo que comparar) Deberia de llegar el mayor a [0], o lo veo mal?

Comment: @MaximoChalian. Es dìfiicl visualizarlo en abstracto. Lo mejor para ver como funciona es hacerlo a mano. Toma una lista desordenada, como [4, 2, 5, 1, 3] y ejecuta el algoritmo a mano, con làpiz y papel.

Answer (score -2):

ahi lo que haces es obtener el valor menor, y lo vas recorriendo hasta el ultimo index, ya que haces un if valorx < valorx+1

```
if ingreso_acomulado[x] < ingreso_acomulado[x+1]:
```

Si ejecuto el siguiente codigo:

```
>>> lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for x in range(len(lista)-1):
...  if lista[x] < lista[x-1]:
...   lista[x], lista[x+1] = lista[x+1], lista[x]
...
```

El Resultado sera:

```
>>> lista
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
```

Si ejecuto ese for 2 veces obtendras:

```
>>> lista
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 1]
```

Es decir se podria decir que capturas el valor menor y lo arrastras hasta el final de la lista, para que se ordene la lista tendrias que ejecutar un for dentro de ese for para que se compare con todos los valores. A mi punto de vista eso es mas tardado.

En el otro caso donde comparas si es mayor:

```
if ingreso_acomulado[x] > ingreso_acomulado[x+1]:
```

Ahi lo que haces es capturar el valor mayor y lo llevas al final de la lista, por ejemplo si ejecuto el siguiente codigo:

```
>>> lista = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> for x in range(len(lista)-1):
...  if lista[x] > lista[x+1]:
...   lista[x], lista[x+1] = lista[x+1], lista[x]
... 
>>> lista
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]
```

Ahi me captura el valor mayor y lo lleva al final de la lista.

Lo que yo podria proponer es que el range con el que recorres la lista sea reverso y capturar el valor mayor, por ejemplo:

```
>>> lista = range(1,11)
>>> lista
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lista_de_indices = range(len(lista)-1)
>>> lista_de_indices
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> lista_de_indices.reverse()
>>> lista_de_indices
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> for x in lista_de_indices:
...  if lista[x+1] > lista [x]:
...   lista[x], lista[x+1] = lista[x+1], lista[x]
... 
>>> lista
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Explicacion: creo la lista, no importa que esta este ordenada, depues creo la lista que recorrera el for, pero la hago inversa o de reversa para que recorra la lista del ultimo index al primero,

```
>>> lista_de_indices = range(len(lista)-1)
>>> lista_de_indices
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> lista_de_indices.reverse()
>>> lista_de_indices
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

y en el for trato de capturar el valor mayor usando:

```
if lista[x+1] > lista [x]:
```

y realizo el intercambio de valores usando:

```
lista[x], lista[x+1] = lista[x+1], lista[x]
```

Claro esta que tambien tu parte del codigo usando aux es valido. Asi logramos capturar y arrastrar el valor mayor al principio, sin ordenar completamente la lista.

Espero saberme explicar.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Tu método no ordena. Pruebalo con `lista = [110, 20, 34, 4, 150, 600, 72, 8, 19, 10]`. Produce `[110, 34, 4, 20, 150, 600, 8, 72, 10, 19]`, o algun otro valor, según que versión del método uses.

Comment: Tal y como comenta @CandidMoe la respuesta no satisface correctamente la pregunta formulada por lo que, puedes editarla y mejorarla o por el contrario, eliminarla. Saludos

Comment: exacto, mensione que no ordena la lista completamente, para eso tendrias que hacer un for dentro de ese for para comparar todos los valores o utilizar metodo sort puede ser creando una tupla, solo satisface la respuesta de obtener el valor mayor en en indice cero.

Comment: Usando lista = [110, 20, 34, 4, 150, 600, 72, 8, 19, 10]
el resultado es:
>>>lista
[600, 110, 20, 34, 4, 150, 72, 19, 8, 10]